# Links in map markers are for default language pages, not localized

Tags: uri, navigation, i18n-l10n, google-maps

I am building a multilingual website where a page will display all locations on a map. Each marker on a map has a link to the location's page. However, only links to English pages are displayed in markers. I have tried both Geofield Map and Leaflet to no avail.

How can I make urls in map markers to be language specific?

Given the fact that I couldn't find an answer on the web, I might have missed something simple. I am new to drupal and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but how we can know what simple thing you missed, if you don't show us how did you implement markers and show them on a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

When creating View I added Language into Fields and Language into Filter Criteria.

That simple!